# Form display PHP HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `PHP` files that interact with eachother, and I have a function called `display_lang_offer()` on the `output.php` file that gets called in the `lang_offer.php` file which is shown below:

```
function display_lang_offer(){
  //languages offered
?> 
<form>
  <select name="languages">
    <option></option>
    <option value"html">HTML</option>
    <option value"css">CSS</option>
    <option value"js">JavaScript</option>
    <option value"csharp">C#</option>
    <option value"php">PHP</option>
    <option value"java">Java</option>
    <option value"phython">Phython</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</form>
<div class="section" id="html">html content here</div>
<div class="section" id="css">CSS content here</div>
<div class="section" id="js">js content here</div>
<div class="section" id="csharp">csharp content here</div>
<div class="section" id="php">php content here</div> 
<div class="section" id="java">java content here</div>
<div class="section" id="phython">phython content here</div>
```

And the `Javascript` is:

```
var id;
$("#languages").on("change",function(){
id=$(this).val();
$(".section").hide();
$("#"+id).stop().show();
})
```

And the `CSS` is:

```
.section{display:none}
```

How do I get it, that when I select the `HTML` option, the `HTML` content gets displayed? Then if I choose the `Java` option, the `HTML` option disappears and the `Java` one appears.

**Edit**

The entire function now is:

```
function display_lang_offer(){
  //languages offered
?> 
<script>
var id;
$("#languages").on("change",function(){
id=$(this).val();
$(".section").hide();
$("#"+id).stop().show();
})
</script>
<style>
.section{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="languages"id="languages">
    <option></option>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="csharp">C#</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

</form>
<div class="section" id="html">html content here</div>
<div class="section" id="css">CSS content here</div>
<div class="section" id="js">js content here</div>
<div class="section" id="csharp">csharp content here</div>
<div class="section" id="php">php content here</div> 
<div class="section" id="java">java content here</div>
<div class="section" id="python">python content here</div>
```

I've tried both answers but neither seem to work

Comment: `$("#languages")`--- I don't see that ID on your select element

Comment: @DaniP where would it go?

Comment: `<select id="languages">`or check the answer from @JorgeObregon

Comment: this: `name` != `id`. `$('#foo')` is NOT going to find `<select name="foo">`

Comment: @JonSmith if the answer worked, please flag it as 'accepted' for the community to know it works. Cheers! :D

Comment: I've tried both answers but for some reason, it's not doing anything?

Comment: I note that your PHP function is not terminated in either block of example code. If this is the case in your actual code, then it would result in a syntax error. In this case, you can fix the problem by adding `<?php } ?>` to the end of the file. However, that said, I can't really see any benefit for you for having all that HTML code embedded in a PHP function anyway, as you don't have any PHP code within the HTML. You'd be better off having it as a separate plain HTML file, and have your `display_lang_offer()` function either `include()` it or redirect to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

1. `<option value"java">Java</option>` you are missing `=` between value and string so calling `.val()` gets text instead of value (as it is broken)
2. You did not set id on your `select` element. If you want to use `$("#languages")` add id value on it `<select name="languages" id="languages">`
3. You need to put script after html.

The following snippet shows working code with only necessary fixes, I did not set id on select but instead used selector based on name:

```js
var id;
$("[name=languages]").on("change",function(){
 id = $(this).val();
 $(".section").hide();
 $("#"+id).show();
})
```

```css
.section { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="languages">
    <option></option>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="csharp">C#</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="phython">Phython</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
<div class="section" id="html">html content here</div>
<div class="section" id="css">CSS content here</div>
<div class="section" id="js">js content here</div>
<div class="section" id="csharp">csharp content here</div>
<div class="section" id="php">php content here</div> 
<div class="section" id="java">java content here</div>
<div class="section" id="phython">phython content here</div>
```

The entire function should be like (but you propably don't need these extra php tags):

```
<?php
function display_lang_offer(){
  ?>
  <style>
  .section{display:none;}
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form>
    <select name="languages"id="languages">
      <option></option>
      <option value="html">HTML</option>
      <option value="css">CSS</option>
      <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
      <option value="csharp">C#</option>
      <option value="php">PHP</option>
      <option value="java">Java</option>
      <option value="python">Python</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

  </form>
  <div class="section" id="html">html content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="css">CSS content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="js">js content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="csharp">csharp content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="php">php content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="java">java content here</div>
  <div class="section" id="python">python content here</div>
  <script>
    var id;
    $("#languages").on("change",function(){
    id=$(this).val();
    $(".section").hide();
    $("#"+id).stop().show();
    })
    </script>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your js with this:

```
var id;
$('[name="languages"]').on("change",function(){
  id=$(this).val();
  $(".section").hide();
  $("#"+id).show();
})
```

---

Another option is to replace:

```
<select name="languages">
```

with:

```
<select name="languages" id="languages">
```